# Opencart code editing using IDE is not working

Tags: opencart-3

I am trying to configure OpenCart 3 and want to customise it's UI. But any change that I make in the code using netbeans IDE is not getting reflected. I tried adding an image in header.twig but the image did not appear. However when I do the same from it's admin panels the change takes place immediately. 
Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that opencart 3 uses template caching and thus any change I made was not reflecting. So to solve the problem:

1. Go to the admin account then a gear icon and turn off caching for template and scss.
2. Go to system/storage/cache delete everything and you are good to go.

Comment: "Go to system/storage/cache delete everything and you are good to go." Not everything!!! please leave `index.html`.